# How to fix "ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine." when creating a scheduled task with Administrator credentials?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

Using a non-Administrator (or Administrator) `cmd.exe`, I enter the following command to create a scheduled task with Administrator credentials `admin` and `P@ssw0rd`:

```
schtasks /CREATE /S %computername% /U admin /P P@ssw0rd /RU SYSTEM /SC ONLOGON /TN SYSTEM_notepad /TR C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.
```

However, I get the error message `ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.`.

Is it some kind of group policy that prevents credentials from being stored with the scheduled task? If so, how to disable it?

AFAIK: `/U` and `/P` specify the account for which to run `schtasks`, whereas `/RU` and `/RP` specify the account for which the task itself is run.

As seen below, `admin` indeed is a member of the Administrators group:

```
net localgroup administrators
Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuraExpressService
di3dh7
admin
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Strictly it is a bug in schtasks.exe
I found a weird workaround/trick, using the Hosts. file! See https://eskerahn.dk/wordpress/?p=2724 I only tried it with /Query, but would be surprised if it did not handle the other ones as well

Comment: Why a downvote? Why comment? The workaround would be as much a 'solution' as many other solutions. Sometimes it seems that help are simply not appreciated...